# AWS LAMBDA: Accessing request headers and body of different content types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to deploy a lambda function with aws api gateway. I was able to succesfully deploy and test POST and GET methods with **Content-Type: application/json** by following this blog: http://kennbrodhagen.net/2015/12/06/how-to-create-a-request-object-for-your-lambda-event-from-api-gateway/

I want my same lambda function to handle requests of content-type : `text/plain`, `x-www-form-urlencoded` also.

The problem with integration template is that we have to define the content-type before hand. So if I make a integration template of `Content-type: text/plain` how can I call that integration template when the api request of `text/plain` is made to the url.
How can I invoke different integration templates based on the Content-Type of the api request?

any tips on that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I got your problem right r not.

From my understanding if you are passing any header information or query string parameters and the content type is text/plain you can map the template like this

```
{
    "prod_Id" : "$input.params('prod_Id')"
}
```

where product id can be the header or query string parameter.

you can find it in my [blog](http://blog.cloudthat.com/deep-dive-into-the-aws-api-gateway/) in `'how to pass query string section`

Comment: What happens to the request if I create two integration mapping templates 1. text/plain 2. application/json. ?

Comment: so whatever request you will get from whichever template it will work accordingly